# Allow user to navigate while file upload is in progress

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am building a Rails application that allows users to upload images using jQuery file uploads. I am trying to make it work like dropbox, where when the upload is happening the user can still access different parts of the website.

How would I go about this? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: check for https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job or https://github.com/resque/resque which might accomplish your task, it's like having a separate thread or process running background.

Comment: I don't think she's asking that. She wants something like how Dropbox and Google Drive does. As in, when uploading a bunch of files, the users can still navigate to other pages and other perform other operations.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you just this soluiton. Use `gem 'refile'`.

It offers you async loading to the storage. You can get answer of the server (file id) and store it in the session. I think this is appropriate way, but it doesn't use jquery file upload.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was hoping that I could do this asynchronous uploads by binding the uploads to a modal dialogue, so that the user can click on other things throughout the site.

Comment: What's wrong? You can use async js to navigate user through site while file uploads